# How to get total number of minutes in an INTERVAL in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, intervals

After subtracting 2 dates `(ended_at - created_at)` I have a time interval like `0-0 0 1:8:23.810192`. How do I get total number of minutes in the interval which is 68 in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE_DIFF does not support MINUTE granularity.

But based on your result values of time: "1:8:23.810192" I am assuming that the dates you have (ended_at and created_at) are actually stored as timestamps.

In that case, you can just use timestamp_diff function and get the minutes directly like this:
Example:

```
select timestamp_diff(current_timestamp(), timestamp_sub(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), MINUTE)
```

=> 1440

For your use case: it will be:
select timestamp_diff(ended_at, created_at, MINUTE)

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff